# Determine $P(X > n +k\mid X > n)$

Tags: probability

> Bob is at the shooting range. 
>   With probability $\frac{1}{3}$ Bob hits the target. 
>   Every shot is independent of the previous ones. 
>   Bob starts and keeps shooting until he hits the target. 
>   Let the random variable $X$ be the number of the shot that first hits the target. 
>   For integers $n$ and $k$, determine $P(X > n +k\mid X > n)$.

I start working on the conditional probability that becomes: $P(X > n +k\mid X > n)=\frac{P(X > n + k\:\cap\:X > n)}{P(X > n)}=\frac{P(X > n+ k)}{P(X > n)}$ 
Now how can I compute the probabilities from the data that I know, which distribution should I use, or how can I use the probabilities given in the question?

Comment: What does "$X \gt n$" mean in words? Can you find $P(X \gt n)$?

Comment: Is the probability that the number of the shot that first hits the target is greater than a positive integer $n$. No, I don't.. :(

Comment: Does Alice shoot too? This is not clear.

Comment: No, only Bob, I'll edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Observe that event $\{X>m\}$ is the same as the event that the first $m$ attempts did not succeed.

Find the probability of this event for $m=n$ and for $m=n+k$.

Google on "geometric distribution".

Comment: Thanks for the hint, so for a geometric distribution $P(X=m)=(1-p)^{m-1}$ and $P(X>m)=(1-p)^{m-1}$ right?

Comment: $P(X>m)=P(\text{first fails and …and }m\text{-th fails})=(1-p)^m$

Comment: What you write is not Bernoulli distribution? Should I use Geometric for this example?

Comment: $X$ has geometric distribution here and consequently $P(X>m)=(1-p)^m$. Further $P(X=m)=(1-p)^{m-1}p$ but that is not relevant. You only need $P(X>m)$.

Comment: Thanks for the help, now it's clear!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The way I understand this is:

What's the probability that it will take at least n+k shots to git the target given that it will take  at least n shots?

So I imagine this scenario:

Bob already took n shots (and missed), what's the probability that he'll have to take at least k more shots before he hits the target?

Note the condition given: Every shot is independent of the previous ones.

So to me it is clear that it doesn't matter that Bob already took n shots and missed. The chances he'll need k more shots now is the same as if he had just now started trying. In other words:

P(X > n + k | X > n) = P(X > k)

Comment: This makes sense, thanks for the hint!

Comment: This is the memoryless property of the geometric distribution

Answer (score 1):

The probability of Bob not hitting the target is $2/3$, so the probability that he misses $x$ times is $(2/3)^x$, since the individual shots are independent. How could you express the statement "Bob misses the target $n$ times" symbolically?

Comment: $P(X>n)=(1-\frac{1}{3})^{n-1} right?$

Comment: not quite: for $X>n$ he has to miss $n$ times